# php div content find

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the content from a div. This is my example:

```
<div id="holder">
  <div class="drop_down">
    <select name="lists" id="lists" onchange="changeDropDown(this);">
        <option value="175" url="/90/175">
        Option 1    </option>
        <option value="176" url="/90/176">
        Option 2    </option>
        <option value="185" url="/90/177">
        Option 3    </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need iterate to get all the urls in the select, I only need these texts: "/90/175", "/90/176", ..

I'm trying to get via file_get_html using this code:

```
$html = file_get_html($path);
$con_div = $html->find('div.drop_down',0);
echo $con_div->plaintext;
```

but my output is: Option 1, Option 2, Option 3...

somebody can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Can we use JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: It says "php" in the Q title.

Comment: If you are using a DOM parser (simple html dom?), you need to select and iterate through the `option` elements and get the `url` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using the [DOM API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$urls = array();

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTMLFile($filePath);

$selectListsNode = $domDocument->getElementById('lists');

$optionsNodes  = $selectListsNode->getElementsByTagName('option');
foreach($optionsNodes as $optionNode) {
    if( $optionNode->hasAttribute('url') ) {
        $urls []= $optionNode->getAttribute('url');
    }
}
```

`print_r($url);` outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => /90/175 [1] => /90/176 [2] => /90/177 )
```

If you really want to get the "urls" from all the ".drop_down" descendants:

```
$urls = array();

$filePath = 'http://localhost/Test/m/index.html';
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTMLFile($filePath);

$xpathExpression = '//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " drop_down ")]';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$divDropDownNodes = $xpath->query($xpathExpression);

foreach($divDropDownNodes as $divDropDownNode) {
    $optionsNodes  = $divDropDownNode->getElementsByTagName('option');
    foreach($optionsNodes as $optionNode) {
        if( $optionNode->hasAttribute('url') ) {
            $urls []= $optionNode->getAttribute('url');
        }
    }
}
```

Notice though that "url" is not a valid HTML attribute.
I recommend you to change it to "data-url", if you're using HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `$e->plaintext` you will get the text values of all child nodes with all tags stripped out. So of course you're not going to get the url attributes, it's something else all together!

This should get you what you want:

```
$html = file_get_html($path);
$con_div = $html->find('#lists',0);
$options = $con_div->children();
foreach($options as $option) {
    echo $option->url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all` is your friend:

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/url="(.*)"/', '<div id="holder">
  <div class="drop_down">
    <select name="lists" id="lists" onchange="changeDropDown(this);">
        <option value="175" url="/90/175">
        Option 1    </option>
        <option value="176" url="/90/176">
        Option 2    </option>
        <option value="185" url="/90/177">
        Option 3    </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>', $matches);
```

It will fill $matches like

```
$matches = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'url="/90/175"',
    1 => 'url="/90/176"',
    2 => 'url="/90/177"',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '/90/175',
    1 => '/90/176',
    2 => '/90/177',
  ),
);
```

However, depending on what you are doing, it might be better to use php's [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).

Comment: Obligatory "don't parse html with regexps!" comment.

Comment: The OP is using PHP's DOM parser, they just don't understand how it works.

Comment: That's why I put the last line there: However, depending on what you are doing, it might be better to use php's DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` function to iterate on them then get their values.
This would help: http://jsfiddle.net/f49bLnmy/

And here's the code if you don't want to go to jsfiddle

```
<div id="holder">
  <div class="drop_down">
    <select name="lists" id="lists" onchange="changeDropDown(this);">
        <option value="175" url="/90/175">
        Option 1    </option>
        <option value="176" url="/90/176">
        Option 2    </option>
        <option value="185" url="/90/177">
        Option 3    </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("option").each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("url"));
        //$(this).attr("url") >> Use this line to get the values
    });
});
</script>
```

And in order to use these values in PHP page, you can sen an `ajax` request with the values and then split them in php array

Use this script for that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var urls= "";
        $("option").each(function(i){
            urls += $(this).attr("url");
            if(i < $("option").length - 1)
                urls += ",";
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "../phppage.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {data: urls},
            success: function(p_data)
            {
                alert(p_data);
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

PHP Page

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$array = explode(",", $data);
echo ($array);
```

Comment: This is a PHP question - see question title and tags.

Comment: @ialarmedalien, sorry I didn't noticed, I will edit it and use ajax request with these values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an solution if you're required to use the PHP DOM Parser:

```
$html = file_get_html($path);
foreach($html->find('div.drop_down select#lists option') as $option)
{
   echo "Value:" . $option->value . "; URL:" . $option->url . PHP_EOL;
}
```